# How to assign values to an optional message field in protobuf?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have below proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";
package my_proto;
message ID
{
   optional uint64 id_upper = 1;
   optional uint64 id_lower = 2;
}
message mymessage
{
   optional ID id = 1;

}
```

And I tried assigning value to ID field using below python script

```
import my_proto_pb2

message = my_proto_pb2.mymessage()
id = message.id()
id.id_upper = 10
id.id_lower = 20
```

But I got below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_message.py", line 4, in <module>
    id = message.id()
TypeError: 'ID' object is not callable
```

May I know why it is throwing this error? Also, how can I assign value to an 'optional' message field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing parenthesis here:
`id = message.id()` to `id = message.id`

another way to do this:

```
thisid = ID()
thisid.id_upper = 10
thisid.id_lower = 20
message = mymessage()
message.id = thisid
```